# IRSSI logs variables?

Tags: logging, google-talk, irssi, xmpp

I'm using IRSSI with XMPP and GTalk, and logs are formatted as
follows:

```
autolog_path = "~/.irssi/logs/$tag/$0.%y-%m-%d.log"
```

The problem is, it generates this log file when the user is connected
from the web chat interface:

```
user@gmail.com_gmail.8FCE4E05.12-02-19.log
```

and the following log when the user is connected from Android client:

```
user@gmail.com_android7245d601efb6.12-02-19.log
```

So, log reading is really a mess. Moreover, the number after "gmail"
and "android" seems to be assigned randomly from Google, and it can
vary trough the time. So, for the same user I can have:

```
user@gmail.com_gmail.G9GA6D06.11-12-19.log
user@gmail.com_gmail.8FCE4E05.12-02-19.log
user@gmail.com_android64w6d6895shf.12-02-19.log
user@gmail.com_android7245d601efb6.12-02-19.log
```

I'm searching for a way to truncate the user name in logs before
the "_", creating a client-independent log file for the same user,
like:

```
user@gmail.com.12-02-19.log
```

I've read the docs, googled until headache, but nothing. I'm using IRSSI 0.8.15 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Thank you ;)

Comment: This would have to be fixed in irssi-xmpp, I think, not in the irssi core.

Comment: I've solved enabling IMAP support to chatlogs in Gmail, and syncing them offline with OfflineIMAP, but I cannot read them with IRSSI anyway :(